# Swift Xcode Timer: Expected Declaration

Tags: swift, xcode, timer

I have been having trouble making my timer app so far and so I was able to narrow the problem down to my timer. I fixed one part wrong with it but for some reason, it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
var timer = Timer()
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.processTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It gives me the `Expected Declaration` error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to start the timer by calling timer.fire()

Comment: @Vaquita You don't need and that's not the reason of the error.